# VMware 8.0 transferring from the host to the VM is slow, why?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, home-networking, file-transfer

If I copy files on my hdd to the same hdd I should get up to 250MB/sec on my SSD.  When I however network from the vmware and copy files from the host computer (same pc) it is really slow like 30MB / sec, why would it go so slowly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Networking is slower than the Sata interface.

[Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet) is rated at 10 or 100 or 1000 Mbit/s at most. While even the slowest [SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) is rated at 1.5 Gbits/s and can go up to 3.0 or 6.0 Gbits/s. So when your transferring data over the network you speed is going to be inherently slower than when compared with using an internal SATA connection, by design.

Comment: Am I to understand that the file transfer is going across the NIC rather than VMWare associated it as being on the same HDD?

Comment: Depending on how you vm's networking is configured when you use networking between a guest os and the host its going to use a network adapter virtual or not.

Comment: Each vm is just a file on your host, if you tell the vm to copy a file from the host using file sharing aka the network it will do it, it has no idea about ssd. If you want better speed try dragging and dropping files etc between the guest and host to get ssd like speeds